# MySQL set offset value with php after the query

Tags: php

I have the follow query

```
 <?php
        $femte = mysqli_query($datacenter, "select vendedor, 
ventatotal, sum(ventatotal) as total from ventas 
WHERE `fecha` = '$datum' group by vendedor order by total desc LIMIT 1 OFFSET 4");
     if(mysqli_num_rows($femte)>0){

    while($denfemte=mysqli_fetch_assoc($femte)){
    ?>
```

I need to run the same query 5 times using offset 1, 2 , 3 , 4 and 5 to display the info I need but it is the same query I just change the offset...

Is there a way to change the offset after the query or something ?

What I would like is only have 1 query and not 5 because the only think I change is the offset in the same page displayed

Comment: Simple. Put it inside loop and repeat it 5 times. Assign the loop variable to offset

Comment: can you give me an example answer please

Comment: Check @Louys code below

Answer (score 0):

A `for` loop?

Using the incrementer `$i` as the `offset` in the query:

```
<?php
$queryCounter = 5;

for($i=1;$i<=$queryCounter;$i++){
  $femte = mysqli_query($datacenter, "select vendedor, ventatotal, sum(ventatotal) as total from ventas 
  WHERE `fecha` = '$datum' group by vendedor order by total desc LIMIT 1 OFFSET ".$i);
  if(mysqli_num_rows($femte)>0){

    while($denfemte=mysqli_fetch_assoc($femte)){
      //...
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Change `,` to `;` in for loop

Comment: @YashParekh: Nice catch!... That certainly was the "syntax error". ;)

Comment: You could also do it with the `LIMIT`, with another variable.